# Add timestamp in Excel column using Powershell

Tags: excel, powershell, timestamp, append, xlsx

I built a Powershell script to append XLSX source content to an XLSX target file. The target file is like this:

```
Date|Name|Node|Cluster
    |ABC PC   HS1
    |XZZ CC   HS2
    |XYZ DD   HS3
```

I want to add a timestamp to the first column for every row that gets appended. How can I achieve this?

```
$excel = Open-ExcelPackage "target.xlsx"
Import-Excel "source.xlsx" -WorksheetName "Node" | 
Export-Excel "target.xlsx" -WorksheetName "Node" -Append
Set-ExcelRow -ExcelPackage $excel -WorksheetName "Node" -Value {Get-Date (Get-Date).AddMonths(-1) -Format "MMM/yy"} -StartColumn 1 
Close-ExcelPackage -ExcelPackage $excel
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

this should work:

```
$date = Get-Date (Get-Date).AddMonths(-1) -Format "MMM/yy"
$object = Import-Excel "source.xlsx" -WorksheetName "Node" 
$object | Add-Member -NotePropertyName Date -NotePropertyValue $(Get-Date (Get-Date).AddMonths(-1) -Format "MMM/yy") 
$object | Export-Excel "target.xlsx" -WorksheetName "Node" -Append
```

Comment: Thanks for your help! Unfortunately it's not working for an existing worksheet. It creates a new sheet.. Furthermore I need the script to be as flexible as possible, because there are different columns (not just name, node, cluster). The power of the import module is that it checks for column names and appends matches. Thanks again.

Comment: Hi, thanks for clearing it up, I modified my answer. Let me know how it works.